# Store the recursive function value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion

```
 function [miu_tau] = CARE_SAV(beta,Yt,t,miu_1)

    if  t > 1  
        miu_tau =beta(1)+beta(2) * ...
                 [CARE_SAV(beta, Yt, t-1, miu_1)]+beta(3)*abs(Yt(t-1));
    else 
        miu_tau = miu_1
    end
```

Hi everyone, I am really new to Matlab and just trying to code up a really simple recursive function. By specifying all the variables, the function works well. But I want to store the value for each miu_tau when I run the function. I tried the following from another answer here

```
function [miu_tau] = CARE_SAV(beta,Yt,t,miu_1)
    miu_tau={}
    if  t > 1  
        miu_tau =[miu_tau; beta(1)+beta(2) * ...
                 [CARE_SAV(beta, Yt, t-1, miu_1)]+beta(3)*abs(Yt(t-1))];
    else 
        miu_tau = [miu_tau;miu_1]
    end
```

It does not work out. Can someone tell me how to store the value from the recursive function here?

Many thanks.

Comment: What are each of the parameters?  Do all of the parameters change with each call?  How are you intending to call this function?  What is the use case of the output?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. By adding a global variable here I can store all the value calculated through the recursion process.

```
function [miu_tau, result] = CARE_SAV(beta,Yt,t,miu_1)
global result;
    if  t > 1  
        miu_tau =beta(1)+beta(2) * ...
                 [CARE_SAV(beta, Yt, t-1, miu_1)]+beta(3)*abs(Yt(t-1));
        result = [result;miu_tau];
    else 
        miu_tau = miu_1
        result = [result;miu_tau];
    end
```

Comment: Global variables should definitely be avoided in this scenario. If you can show us an equation that you're trying to model, we can definitely show you an answer that *doesn't* use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
function [miu_tau] = CARE_SAV(beta,Yt,t,miu_1)

miu_tau=[];
    if  t > 1  
        miu_tau =[miu_tau; beta(1)+beta(2) * ...
                 [CARE_SAV(beta, Yt, t-1, miu_1)]+beta(3)*abs(Yt(t-1))];
    else 
        miu_tau = [miu_tau;miu_1]
    end
```

This should work. Instead of cell, use matrix notation.